# Bringing layers forward or sending back with After Effects expressions

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

I have two solids right next to each other.  At certain points in the timeline, I increase the scale of one or the other for emphasis.  The problem is that one of the solids is located behind the other, so when its scale increases, it's partially blocked.

How can I modify the layer stack using expressions?  I found moveBefore(), moveAfter(), etc., but those appear to be scripting only.

Answer (score 0):

After getting some good advice, there's no way to modify the layer stack via expressions.  This should be handled by making the layers 3D or by creating a duplicate layer further up the stack and flipping the opacity on and off.